# Using the Revealing Module Pattern, why is this object changed?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

Given the following code:

```
var House = function(x, y) {
    var _posX;
    var _posY;

    function init(x,y) {
        _posX = x;
        _posY = y;
    }

    // Auto init
    init(x, y);


    // Public
    return {
        posX: _posX,
        posY: _posY,

        setPosition: function(x, y) {
            _posX = x;
            _posY = y;
        }
    };
};
```

If I create a new House object:

```
var house = new House(3,4);
```

And use the setPosition method to change the position:

```
house.setPosition(100,50);
```

I expected that the house position would still be 3,4.. But it however changed (which is actually what I want, but I don't understand how this is possible?) I dont'understand it since Javascript already returned the position which is 3,4 and I would expect it to be like that all the time, even if I change the position using the set method.

```
console.log(house.posX + ',' + house.posY); // 100,50 (why not 3,4?)
```

Bonus question: is there a proper way to do the init rather than placing it, ugly in the middle of the code?

Comment: how do you determine that the position has changed? It actually changes something, but nothing you can ever inspect with the code you provided.

Comment: you can shorten the code, by replacing everything before the return with `var House = function(_posX, _posY) { return ...`

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the reply. Sorry, not sure whether I understand your comment, I updated my answer. Simply by logging the position after changing the code.
Regarding your second comment, that would make everything public right?

Comment: for me, the code works as expected, and `console.log(house.posX + ',' + house.posY)` shows `3,4`. Can you provide some testarea for us, where you can reproduce this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is due to a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

> Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables
>   (variables that are used locally, but defined in an enclosing scope).
>   In other words, these functions 'remember' the environment in which
>   they were created.

`_posx` and `_posy` were defined in a surrounding scope and `setPosition` remembers it.

By the way, I think that `init` should be removed and you should directly assign `_posx` and `_posy` in your constructor function.